# Creating a new column based on values from other columns in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with one column showing currencies and another showing prices. I want to create a new column that standardizes the prices to USD based on the values from the other two columns.

eg.

```
  currency   price
  SGD        100
  USD        80
  EUR        75
```

the new column would have conditions similar to

if currency == SGD:
   price = price / 1.37 etc.

so in the end it would look like

```
  currency   price   new_price
  SGD        100     72.99
  USD        80      80
  EUR        75      65.22
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a dictionary containing all the currency conversions and then divide the price column by currency column [mapped](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) to the dictionary.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'currency': ['SGD', 'USD', 'EUR'], 
                   'price': [100, 80, 75]})
to_usd = {'USD': 1.0, 'SGD': 1.37, 'EUR': 1.15}
df['new_price'] = df.price / df.currency.map(to_usd)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  currency  price  new_price
0      SGD    100  72.992701
1      USD     80  80.000000
2      EUR     75  65.217391
```